# Most ocuring chatacter in a cell

Tags: google-sheets

What's the formula to find which is the most frequent character in a cell in Google Sheets?
E.G. In cell N8 it says: "What's your name?". I'd like the formula to return "a", as it is the most frequent character in N8.

Comment: `A` is tied as the most frequent character along with `space`. What happens in a tie?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the total distribution like this:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, REPT("(.)", LEN(A1)))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

notice that two empty spaces are counted as well

if you want to skip them use:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, REPT("(.)", LEN(A1)))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 <> ' ' group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

also, keep in mind that this is case-sensitive:

[image]

to make it case-insensitive use:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(A1), REPT("(.)", LEN(A1)))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 <> ' ' group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

so to get the top value only use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(A1), REPT("(.)", LEN(A1)))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 <> ' ' group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1)''"), 1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Amusingly, our very different formulas are exactly the same length `175` if you strip out superfluous characters (i.e. your returns and extra spaces for readability).

Comment: @pgSystemTester https://i.stack.imgur.com/67FjC.png :)

Comment: Ouch... in my defense, I am actually at 174, as I forgot to remove a `$` sign from my reference, so you only beat me by 26...

Comment: @pgSystemTester https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF6P9.png :)

Comment: Ouch ouch... reminds me dancing on a Fortnite opponent after eliminating them...  [Player() handing me the L](https://youtu.be/C3tASSETUTE?t=245)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=index(Sort(filter({LEN(substitute($A$1,mid($A$1,ROw(A:A),1),"")),mid($A$1,ROw(A:A),1)},Row(A:A)<= LEN(A1)),1,true),1,2)
```

I'm not sure what you'd expect for when there's a tie, but it would consistently return the character most used. If you wanted to skip spaces, you could do this...

```
=index(Sort(filter({LEN(substitute($A$1,mid(substitute($A$1," 
",""),ROw(A:A),1),"")),mid(substitute($A$1," ",""),ROw(A:A),1)},Row(A:A) 
<= LEN(substitute(A1," ",""))),1,true),1,2)
```

Comment: you can do better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2kbq.png

Comment: but to match your case-sensitivity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArnHO.png